# Can a Windows 7 HomeGroup permit VPN connections?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, homegroup, hamachi

Would like to integrate HomeGroup with my VPN (Hamachi/LogMeIn) addresses. Possible?

Comment: In what way do you want to "integrate" them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the limitations of your VPN server, but homegroup works exclusively over IPV6